# Como passar valores via terminal para uma função do programa

Tags: c, funções, linha-de-comando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void soma(int a,int b);
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("A soma=");
    return 0;
}

void soma(int a,int b){
    printf("%d\n",a+b);
}
```

Como passo os valores via terminal para os parâmetros da função `soma()`?

Compilar:

```
cc exemplo.c -o exemplo
```

Executar (não funciona):

```
./exemplo < soma 3 4
```

Comment: O que é esse `< soma` na chamada à aplicação ? Qual o seu objetivo ? A ideia é poder especificar a operação diretamente na chamada ?

Comment: o objectivo e passar um valor para "a" e "b" e apresentar a soma chamando o programa principal primeiro

Comment: E porque o texto `soma` e o `<` são incluidos na chamada ?

Comment: o caracter "<" e para aceder a uma zona dentro programa penso(a funcao) mas nao esta a apresentar o resultado. Quando faço ./exemplo < soma 3 4 deveria escrever como resultado "A soma =7"

Comment: @user48571 A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme resposta anterior, acho que é isto que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int soma(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Soma: %d", soma((int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) + (int)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10)));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Strtol2.c).

Mas se quiser fazer a impressão separada (eu não faria, mas eu sequer teria essa função auxiliar também:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void soma(int a, int b) {
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Soma: ");
    soma((int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) + (int)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10))
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Strtol3.c).

Assim faria um pouco mais de sentido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int soma(char *primeiro, char *segundo) {
    return (int)strtol(primeiro, NULL, 10) + (int)strtol(segundo, NULL, 10));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Soma: %d", soma(argv[1], argv[2]));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Strtol4.c).

Não deve passar o "soma". Se a intenção é chamar a função de acordo com o texto, e não está na pergunta, aí complica um pouco, ou bastante, dependendo da técnica necessária.

Comment: assim eu sei fazer mas eu quero seleccionar uma funcao em especifico nao e so esta ./exemplo < divide 4 2 (chamada de outra funcao)

Comment: Você sabe, mas não fez. Então você precisa perguntar o que você quer. Leia sua pergunta e veja se tem isso nela. Não tem, você está perguntando coisas diferentes do que você quer de fato.

Comment: O comando que eu estou a solicitar é bem claro, eu preciso de chamar um funcao especifica que esta dentro de um programa e quero que me devolva o resultado passando valores para a mesma. A questão é como passo esses valores para essa funcao via execução terminal ./exemplo < soma 3 4 (nao funciona). Isto aki nao é um argumento do programa principal "< soma 3 4"